# How to get store by reference in ExtJS MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

In ExtJS MVC controller we have `stores` property which is array of Stores.

ExtJS automatically generates getter functions for every store (`this.getUsersStore` for `Users` store etc.)

But what should we do if our store is on 2nd level of folders hierarchy and has name of `shop.Users`?

Is there any auto getters for such stores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That get's handled. In your example you get a getter named `getShopUsersStore()`

The getter creater splits for each dot and concat each of these strings capitalized.